# Solving $ e^z + 2 = 0$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

Why is this true?

> If $\;  e^z + 2 = 0$ and $z \in
>  \Bbb C$, $\;$  then $\;$ $z = \ln 2 + i\,\pi$.

Probably simple question but I am not sure how to deal with it.

Comment: Use [Euler's formla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula): $e^{x+i y} = x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))$

Comment: It's actually NOT true (as an implication). In general, $e^z$ is periodic with period $2i\pi$, so the solutions are actually $$z=\ln2 + (2\mathbb Z+1)i\pi,$$ i.e., $z=\ln 2 \pm i\pi, \ln2\pm 3i\pi,\dots$.

Comment: Why all the answers limit themselves to show $e^z=e^{z_0}$ and say $z_0$ is one solution, without saying that the equation has actually an infinity of solutions which are $z=z_0+2ik\pi$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$ as Luke indicated above ?

Comment: @zwim I haven't stated that the solution is unique. Furthermore, I think that in my answer, it is clear that you should find $y$ such that $i\cdot 0=i\cdot \sin(y)$ and $-1=\cos(y)$ so that $y= k \pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because
$$z=\ln 2 +i \pi \implies e^z =e^{\ln 2+i \pi}=e^{\ln 2}e^{i\pi}=2 \cdot(-1)=-2,$$ so $e^z+2=0$.

I used the identity $e^{i \pi}=-1$.

I just noticed that you wanted to imply the first from the latter, this is the other way around, since the other implication does not hold in general.

Comment: That is actually a very nice trick.

Answer (score 2):

$$e^z+2=0\implies e^z=-2\,,\,k\in\Bbb Z\implies$$

$$z=\text{Log}(-2)=\log|-2|+i\arg(-2)=\log2+i\pi$$

When in the above we take the principal arugment.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that if we have some: $z\in\mathbb{C}$ we can represent this as $z=x+jy$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. So if we want to take the natural logarithm we must instead use the polar system:
$$\ln(z)=\ln(x+jy)=\ln(re^{j\theta})$$
And this can easily be split up into:
$$\ln(re^{j\theta})=\ln(r)+j\theta$$
In this context we have:
$$e^z+2=0\implies z=\ln(-2)$$
And we can say that:
$$-2=2e^{j\pi}\therefore \ln(-2)=\ln(2)+j\pi$$
And so:
$$z=\ln(2)+j\pi$$
However note that the imaginary part of this can make many forms since the function $e^z$ is periodic as can be seen by its definition $e^{j\theta}=\cos\theta+j\sin\theta$

Comment: note that $z=\ln(2)+(2n+1)i\pi$ is true for all positive integers $n$ due to $e^{ix}$ being a periodic function

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Note that $e^z+2=0$ if and only if $e^z = -2 = -2+i\cdot 0 $ and use [Euler's formla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula): 
$$e^{x+i y} = e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))\qquad \forall x,y\in \Bbb R.$$

Comment: $e^{x+iy}=e^{x}(\cos y+i \sin y)$ !

Comment: @GCab of course, thank you for pointing out the typo...